# Jest: How to mock a promise on the same file for resolve and reject options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

So I am attempting to test the positive and negative sides of my implementation. If I do this:

```
jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn((url: string) => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData }))
}));

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
    console.log('error result');
    return Promise.reject(mockError);
  })
}));
```

Then the only test passing will be the last one declared. In the above case, it will be the `reject` case which will pass and the first mock will be ignored.

This is my whole test:

```
// @ts-ignore
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import ApiService from './apiService';

const mockData = {};
const mockError = { message: 'Smth Bad Happened' };

const firstCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => data);
const secondCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => data);

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn((url: string) => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData }))
}));

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
    console.log('error result');
    return Promise.reject(mockError);
  })
}));

describe('apiService', () => {
  it('should call callbacks consequently', done => {
    ApiService.makeApiCall('testUrl', firstCallback, secondCallback).then(() => {
      expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledWith(mockData);

      expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledWith(firstCallback(mockData));
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should handle error', done => {
    console.error = jest.fn();
    ApiService.makeApiCall('testUrl', firstCallback, secondCallback).then(() => {
      expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
      expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
      expect(console.error).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(console.error).toBeCalledWith('ApiClient testUrl', mockError);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

As it is right now, the test passing is `should handle error` which is the second one, but if I have switch the positions from

```
jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn((url: string) => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData }))
}));

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
    console.log('error result');
    return Promise.reject(mockError);
  })
}));
```

To

```
jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
    console.log('error result');
    return Promise.reject(mockError);
  })
}));

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn((url: string) => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData }))
}));
```

then the test passing will be `should call callbacks consequently`, so what can I do to mock both reject and resolve without interfering one with the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've reached this question while I was looking for a good practice to do that, because I had the same problem but I found a workaround to make it work. And although I suppose you already solved this issue, I'll leave here my temporary solution for future readers.

Basically I overridden the mock implementation of the method right in the test where I want to reject the promise.

So I would get rid of the **reject** implementation before the `describe` declaration and add it in the `'should handle error'` test by this way:

```
ApiClient.get: jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
    console.log('error result');
    return Promise.reject(mockError);
})
```

Your final test would look like this:

```
// @ts-ignore
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import ApiService from './apiService';

const mockData = {};
const mockError = { message: 'Smth Bad Happened' };

const firstCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => data);
const secondCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => data);

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => ({
  get: jest.fn((url: string) => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData }))
}));

describe('apiService', () => {
  it('should call callbacks consequently', done => {
    ApiService.makeApiCall('testUrl', firstCallback, secondCallback).then(() => {
      expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledWith(mockData);

      expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledWith(firstCallback(mockData));
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should handle error', done => {
    ApiClient.get: jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
        console.log('error result');
        return Promise.reject(mockError);
    });
    console.error = jest.fn();
    ApiService.makeApiCall('testUrl', firstCallback, secondCallback).then(() => {
      expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
      expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
      expect(console.error).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(console.error).toBeCalledWith('ApiClient testUrl', mockError);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

I think this is not the best way to do it, but it is not bad at all, and it should work for this example.

I'll keep looking for a smarter solution.